# Mongoose NodeJS Express - Edit a specific sub document field

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the following schemas designed in my Node server

---

### SCHEMAS

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const dataSchema = new Schema({
    time: Date,
    value: String
});

const nodeSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String,
    number: Number,
    status: String,
    lastSeen: Date,
    data: [dataSchema]
});

const siteSchema = new Schema({
    code: String,
    name: String,
    description: String,
    totalNodes: Number,
    nodes: [nodeSchema]
});

const Site = mongoose.model('site',siteSchema);
module.exports = Site;
```

### They basically look like this. You can see there are two nodes with some demo data.

### EXAMPLE

```
 {
        "_id": "5fa169473a394829bc485069",
        "code": "xfx3090",
        "name": "Name of this site",
        "description": "Some description",
        "totalNodes": 2,
        "__v": 0,
        "nodes": [
            {
                "_id": "5fa1af361e085b516066d7e2",
                "name": "device name",
                "description": "device description",
                "number": 1,
                "status": "Offline",
                "lastSeen": "2020-11-03T19:27:50.062Z",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "Date": "2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                        "value": "12"
                    },
                    {
                        "Date": "2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                        "Value": "146"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "_id": "5fa1b10f4f24051520f85a58",
                "name": "device name",
                "description": "device description",
                "number": 2,
                "status": "Offline",
                "lastSeen": "2020-11-03T19:35:43.409Z",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "Date": "2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                        "Value": "555"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

My question is how can I update a specific field of a node, in particular how I can update the last seen or the status. It is important to mention that the client making the request will only have access the the site code and the node number. The Object Id's of sites and nodes will not be known.

So far this is what I have, but it only creates one new Object Id for some reason.

Any advice will be appreciated

```
 updateNode: async (req,res,next) => {
        const {siteCode} = req.params;
        const { nodeNumber } = req.params;
        const status = req.body.status;

        const nodeStatus = await Site.findOneAndUpdate({'code': siteCode, 'nodes.number':nodeNumber}, { '$set': {'nodes.$.status': {'status':status}}});

        res.status(200).json({message: 'success'});
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. When asking a question, try to show the output that you received **before** asking the question for us to have more debugging information.

Comment: `Site.findOneAndUpdate({'code': siteCode, 'nodes.number':nodeNumber}, { '$set': {'nodes.$.status': {'status':status}}})` doesn't this work?

Comment: It executes but does not give the result I want. Essentially it creates another Object Id on the data array. I want it to change the online status or the last seen status by only using the site code and the node number

Comment: can you give pic before and after you try and what do you want for the result in real case?

Comment: I dont get with `creates another Object Id on the data array`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do it this way.
I have predefined the `._id`s.
You can do this dynamically if you want. If you are using express you could just use queries. Example `req.query.documentID`. The URL to access it will be `localhost:p/?documentID=5fa169473a394829bc485069&nodeID=5fa1af361e085b516066d7e2`

`p` in localhost is for port

```js
    await Site
        .findOne({ 
            "_id": "5fa169473a394829bc485069",
            "nodes._id": "5fa1af361e085b516066d7e2" 
        })
        .update({ "lastSeen": Date })
        .then(doc => res.json(doc))
        .catch(e => console.log(e))
```

Basically finding a doc with id of `5fa169473a394829bc485069`
Then a `node` with `_id` of `5fa1af361e085b516066d7e2`
And then `update()` method and `{ "lastSeen": Date }` parameter to Date.
That's it!

**EDIT** 
You'll have to create a **VALID** MongoDB object by doing this

```js
app.get("/new", async (req, res) => {
    let Site = new model({
        code: "String",
        name: "String",
        description: "String",
        totalNodes: 2,
        nodes: [
            {
                _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
                name: "String",
                description: "String",
                number: 1,
                status: "offline",
                lastSeen: Date.now(),
                data: [{ "someData": "someData" }]
            },
            {
                _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
                name: "String",
                description: "String",
                number: 2,
                status: "offline",
                lastSeen: Date.now(),
                data: [{ "someData": "someData" }]
            }
        ]
    });

    await Site
        .save()
        .then(doc => {
            console.log(doc);
            res.json(doc);
        })
        .catch(e => console.error(e));
});
```

Everything is loaded with dummy data. Then you update the data like this.

```js
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    await model
        .findOne({ "code": "String" })
        .update({
            "nodes.0.status": "online"
        })
        .then(doc => {
            console.log(doc);
            res.json(doc);
        })
        .catch(e => console.error(e));
})
```

Basically you access the object at the index position 0 ( that means the first post ) like this `nodes.0` and then the status of that object will be respectively `nodes.0.status`. Then you just save the object and that's it!

Comment: Yes this should work, but the problem is that the client making the request will only have access to the node number. Therefore, I was hoping there was a way to do this without the node ID?

Comment: Fortunately, you can! Check out my answer again. I updated it. Took me some time to do it but it was worth it.